# Confusing UX when filtering by compensation

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I was searching for jobs in my area. I saw a list of results, but I missed that none of them were an exact match. The "Create a job alert" link overwhelmed my quick scan of the page.

Here's my search:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?l=Chattanooga%2C+TN%2C+USA&d=20&u=Miles

The confusing part for me was when I added a minimum compensation filter, I got zero results:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?l=Chattanooga%2C+TN%2C+USA&d=20&u=Miles&s=1&c=USD

I took me a long time to figure out that my original search hadn't found any exact matches, and that adding a filter seems to cause even the recommendations to disappear.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention ~ I agree it is confusing. We can probably come up with a simple fix for this. I'll take this back to the team!